# Why is Google API telling me "Forbidden. Request had insufficient authentication scopes"?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

I'm writing my first application to talk to a Google API, I assume once I get it figured out things will make more sense.  It's a C#/Windows application, and I thought I had all the permissions set on the server, but when I run the app it throws a Google.GoogleApiException exception.   I had hoped that somewhere in the Google API docs it would say "this method requires scope authorizations X, Y, and Z" but I can't find it.

The exception content is:

```
{
   "error": {
      "code": 403,
      "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
      "errors": [
         {
            "message": "Insufficient Permission",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
         }
      ],
      "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
      "details": [
         {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo"
            "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT",
            "domain": "googleapis.com",
            "metadata": {
               "method": "ccc.hosted.frontend.directory.v1.DirectoryGroups.List",
               "service": "admin.googleapis.com"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

What I'm trying to do for now, is to read the names of the mailing list groups I've created.  Once I've got that working I'll try to read the names of the members of the groups, and finally actually do some updating of the lists, but for now I'd be happy just to read the names of the groups.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the relevant code:

```
            UserCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new FileStream(jsonFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                try
                {
                    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                        new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryCustomer, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupReadonly, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupMemberReadonly },
                        "user", CancellationToken.None);
                    Debug.WriteLine("[1] credential=" + credential);
                    var ser = new DirectoryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = "UpdateMailGroups"
                    });
                    Debug.WriteLine("ser=" + ser);
                    Debug.WriteLine("ser.Groups=" + ser.Groups);
                    GroupsResource.ListRequest list = ser.Groups.List();
                    Debug.WriteLine("list=" + list);
                    var e = list.Execute();
                    Debug.WriteLine("e=" + e);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("exception: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

EDIT

On the APIs&Services/Credentials page I copied the OAuth 2.0 Client ID; I then went to "Security/API Controls/Domain-wide Delegation" and added a new API client with that client ID and the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly" and finally changed my code so I'm only asking for AdminDirectoryGroupReadonly authorization:

```
credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
   GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
   new[] { DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupReadonly },
   "user", CancellationToken.None);
```

But it gives the same error.

EDIT 2

On the "APIs&Services/Credentials" page there is a section for "Service Accounts" and a single entry for "[company]-mail-updater@email-group-updater.iam.gserviceaccount.com".  I clicked on "Edit service account" and on the page that came up in a section titled "Advanced Settings" was information on Domain-wide Delegation followed by a Client ID.  I copied that Client ID, then went back to the "Security/API Controls/Domain-wide Delegation" page and added that as a new API Client with the same scope.

Same error.

EDIT 3

It's getting so close!  I realized the "user" parameter to the call to GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() needed to be the service account ("[company]-mail-updater@email-group-updater.iam.gserviceaccount.com") instead of just "user".  Running that, it opened a tab in a browser asking for permission which I granted and I didn't get any authorization errors!

But now when I call list.Execute() it throws an exception:

```
GoogleApiException: The service admin has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is BadRequest. Bad Request
Error=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Bad Request [400]
Errors [
    Message[Bad Request] Location[ - ] Reason[badRequest] Domain[global]
]

ErrorResponseContent={
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Bad Request",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

EDIT 4

Adding a line

```
list.Domain = <my website domain>
```

before calling

```
list.Execute()
```

does the trick!

Comment: You are authorizing with a service account. That requires Domain Wide Delegation of Authority to be set up at Workspace and the service account. Once that is done you will then need to add the user email address that the service account is impersonating.

Comment: @JohnHanley - thanks for your info!  Is "authorizing with a service account" what I want to be doing?  Or is there an easier/better way to get authorized?

Comment: @JohnHanley - I think I'm getting closer, but I'm not sure (1) which user email the service account is impersonating, or (2) where to add it.  Thanks!

Comment: DWD is enabled in Workplace. When you create credentials you specify the Workplace email address to impersonate.

Comment: @JohnHanley - I don't remember specifying a user email address when creating any of the credentials, where would I find that information?  On the other hand, there's only one actual user in this domain right now so I've got a pretty good idea who it's got to be (grin).  Where do I "add the user email address that the service account is impersonating"?

Comment: I tried changing "user" to that email address in the call to GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync() and it popped up a tab in the nearest browser window saying "Access Blocked: Authorization Error"

Comment: You specify the email address when you create the credential from the service account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254757/discussion-between-betty-crokker-and-john-hanley).