# Why is Google API telling me "Not Authorized to access this resource/api"?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to write a program that lets me add/edit/remove Google mail groups, and it's been a struggle.  First I got "[Forbidden. Request had insufficient authentication scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76807605/why-is-google-api-telling-me-forbidden-request-had-insufficient-authentication)" and with help from StackOverflow I fixed one thing, then [got the same error again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76821366/google-people-api-what-do-i-need-to-access-an-individual-users-contacts-from) and fixed that.  Then it told me ["Request had insufficient authentication scopes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76854468/why-does-google-api-return-request-had-insufficient-authentication-scopes) and again StackOverflow was able to help me fix that.  Then I got ["Access blocked: [app] can only be used within its own organization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54629180/cant-login-using-google-auth-403-org-internal) and StackOverflow came through yet again.

So here's where I'm at now: in the Google Cloud / APIs and Services / OAuth consent screen, my app is set to Publishing Status: Testing, User type: External.

On my home PC I've got a Chrome window open for my personal gmail account which is not in the same domain as the data the application is accessing.  There are two email addresses listed in the "Test emails" section of the "OAuth consent" screen, neither one is mine or anyone in my personal domain.  I had a Chrome window open that was logged into the domain the application is accessing, but I specifically logged out of that user and closed that window.

When I run the application at home, inside Visual Studio, it's completely happy.  I copied the application to the site where it's going to actually be used, and when I ran it, it said I needed to log into a Google account which I did (and it is an account that is listed on the OAuth consent screen).  It then gives me the error "The service admin has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is forbidden. Not Authorized to use this resource/api".

So I've got two related questions.

1. Based on the way I've got the app set up, it seems like it shouldn't run at home.  Why does the app run, even though I'm not listed as one of the test users?  (if I can get it to fail at home, that makes debugging 100x easier)
2. Why is it giving me this failure?

EDIT

Sorry for the long delay, life happened ...

Here's what the code looks like:

1. Load the JSON file downloaded from the cloud console:

```
{ 
   "installed":{
      "client_id":"[snip].apps.googleusercontent.com",
      "project_id":"[snip]",
      "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_secret":"[snip]",
      "redirect_uris":["http://localhost"]
   }
}
```

2. Create Credential using a service account and passing in the contents of that JSON file:

```
Credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
   GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
   new[] {
      DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroup, PeopleServiceService.Scope.Contacts, DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryGroupMember,
                    DirectoryService.Scope.AdminDirectoryUser
   },
   "app@app.iam.gserviceaccount.com", CancellationToken.None);
```

3. Get the directory service

```
var initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
   HttpClientInitializer = Credential,
   ApplicationName = "[snip]"
};
DirService = new DirectoryService(initializer);
```

Comment: A few thoughts. Is status TESTING set at both home and where it is going to be used?  When you use SMTP the login account and the From address has to be from same account.  Corporate network use Port Forwarding to capture all email ports and send to Corporate Email Server so you cannot access GMAIL from inside the network, You are running a service.  How did you start service?  Default is a system account.  You should run as a service account.

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] however i think my answers is a decent guess as to what your issue is.

Comment: Ermiya Eskandary please don't edit out the part of my question that (1) shows I've done quite a bit of research before posting this, and (2) shows the code in question

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I've added code, let me know if there is more I need to include to show what I'm doing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> HttpStatusCode is forbidden. Not Authorized to use this resource/api"

Normally means that you are using a service account, and have not properly configured domain wide delegation to your google workspace account and / or have not designated the user who you whish to impersonate.

The the could would look something like this with workspaceAdmin being the email address of the user on my domain I wish the service account to impersonate.

```
private static GoogleCredential LoadGoogleCredentails()
    {
        return GoogleCredential.FromFile(PathToServiceAccountKeyFile)
            .CreateScoped(Scopes)
            .CreateWithUser(workspaceAdmin);
    }
```

However as you have not stated that you are using a service account, and have said that you have tried logging in with both a standard Gmail user and a domain user.

What i suspect is that you are using Oauth2 and locally you authorized your code once and it has stored your tokens on your machine.  You are not resetting it so when you run it its using the stored tokens.

Then when you try on your server it does not have the stored tokens so will their for fail.

However your main issue is that a standard gmail domain user can **not** access a google workspace domain account. It will also throw this error. Stop trying to login with your gmail user account. you cant use that api with it.

> Not Authorized to use this resource/api

Comment: how can I delete those stored tokens on my machine?  Where are they stored, and in what form?

Comment: I cant answers that it depends on your code.  Edit your question and show me your code

Comment: your using the default filedatastore creds are stored in %appdata% check this [Google .net – FileDatastore demystified](https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)

Comment: Excellent, that somewhat answers question #1 - by deleting the "Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-app@app.iam.gserviceaccount" file, I'm now getting an "Access blocked: Authorization Error" error when I run it from home inside Developer Studio.  That's not quite the same error I was getting when I run it from the remote site, but close.  I tried adding my email to the list of "Test Users" on the OAuth Consent Screen but still got the same error.

Comment: Access blocked: Authorization Error  <-- can you add the full message to your question.   Also what do you mean by remote site?